# Copy cell range from one worksheet and paste in a different worksheet as a value rather than formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below to copy a range of cells and paste to the next available row on a different worksheet. My issue is that it's pasting the formulas rather than the values. What do I need to change?

```
Private Sub CopyAuditData_Click()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Call Audit Sheet")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("HiddenData")
    DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws1.Range("V1").Copy ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V2").Copy ws2.Range("B" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V3").Copy ws2.Range("C" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V4").Copy ws2.Range("D" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V5").Copy ws2.Range("E" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V6").Copy ws2.Range("F" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V7").Copy ws2.Range("G" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V8").Copy ws2.Range("H" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V9").Copy ws2.Range("I" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V10").Copy ws2.Range("J" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V11").Copy ws2.Range("K" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V12").Copy ws2.Range("L" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V13").Copy ws2.Range("M" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V14").Copy ws2.Range("N" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V15").Copy ws2.Range("O" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V16").Copy ws2.Range("P" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V17").Copy ws2.Range("Q" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V18").Copy ws2.Range("R" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V19").Copy ws2.Range("S" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V20").Copy ws2.Range("T" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V21").Copy ws2.Range("U" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V22").Copy ws2.Range("V" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V23").Copy ws2.Range("W" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V24").Copy ws2.Range("X" & DestRow)
    ws1.Range("V25").Copy ws2.Range("Y" & DestRow)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially transposing rows to columns from one worksheet to another.

Instead of the many lines of copy/paste with specific ranges, use a loop, Reducing 25-50 lines into 3.

To be used in your specific example, because you happen to be transposing rows to columns.  The row number happens to match the column number you are pasting into, so embrace it with a loop.

```
Private Sub CopyAuditData_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim DestRow As Long, lRow As Long

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Call Audit Sheet")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("HiddenData")
    DestRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'CHANGES HERE
    For lRow = 1 To 25
        ws2.Cells(DestRow, lRow).Value = ws1.Cells(lRow, "V").Value 
    Next lRow

End Sub
```

Breaks down like:

Where `lRow = 1`  Using it as both the row of the source and column of target.

`ws2.Cells(DestRow, 1)`  is the same as `ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)`

`ws1.Cells(lRow, "V")` is the same as `ws1.Range("V1")`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ws1.Range("V1").Copy ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)
```

do

```
ws1.Range("V1").Copy
ws2.Range("A" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Note: Has to be 2 lines of code now!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for copy only the values:

Instead of

```
ws1.Range("V1").Copy ws2.Range("A" & DestRow)
```

use

```
ws2.Range("A" & DestRow) = ws1.Range("V1")
```